# Can Metamask read Ethereum Name Service (ENS) addresses?

Tags: metamask, ens

Is Metamask Chrome extension able to read an Ethereum Name Service (ENS) address?

Comment: According to their [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), yes - https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#364-2017-5-8

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but currently only in the "Send" form. Eventually, MetaMask may allow dapps to specify recipient by ENS, and even loading pages by ENS!

Comment: Did MetaMask remove ENS support? I get the `Recipient address is invalid` error: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/168240/61326419-8ef2fe80-a7cb-11e9-97b2-2884af22fb85.png

Comment: No, it was not removed, but it only works on the main network today. You're currently on the Kovan test network. This was originally because there were other ENS registrars on other test networks, but maybe it makes sense to unify over the main-net one.

Comment: ah makes sense; thanks for the response

Comment: I've added this feature request as a new issue on MetaMask's github: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/6916